# Leaflet - click on map object will trigger click on another map object

Tags: leaflet

i have this situation:

[image]

I want that clicking on the circle (buffer) around the marker will trigger a click on the marker.

This is where im creating the circle around the marker:

```
L.geoJSON(buffer).addTo(this.map).on("click", (e)=> marker.fire("click")
```

But unfortunately it doesnt work. The click on the circle is triggered but not triggering the click on the marker.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** this is where im trying to attach the event:

```
this.drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(this.map)
let currentLayer = this.drawnItems[index];

let bufMapObject = L.geoJSON(buffer).addTo(this.map).on("click", (e) => {
                console.log(currentLayer)
                currentLayer.fire("click")
            });
```

The output of console.log(currentLayer) is: 
[image]

Comment: Try calling marker.fire with small time delay.

Comment: unfortunately did not helped..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say wihout the rest of the code why your code is not working. I used Leaflet geoJSON example http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/example.html for testing, just added one marker. Here is the code that works:

```
var myMarker = L.marker([39.744, -105.0043]).bindPopup('My marker.');
myMarker.addTo(map);

L.geoJSON(campus).addTo(map).on('click', function(e) {myMarker.fire('click');} );
```

Comment: Benny67b, feedback is much appreciated around here, by those who answer questions and by those who might have similar problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I really dont know why, but its just not working.
Iv'e edited the question and added the information of the object that im trying to simulate "click" on it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, in order to init `currentLayer` you are accessing `drawnItems` directly with an index. In order to get the layers of the drawnItems I think you should try:

`let currentLayer = this.drawnItems.getLayers()[index];`